# How to make the connection to waiting state by using StreamBuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter

My requirement is to make that StreamBuilder connection state to waiting.

I'm using publish subject, whenever I want to load data in stream builder I'm just adding data to the sink by calling **postStudentsToAssign()** method, here this method making an API call which takes some time, in that time I to want make that streamBuilder  connection state to waiting

**Stream Builder:**

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: studentsBloc.studentsToAssign,
            // initialData: [],
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  // While waiting for the data to load, show a loading spinner.
                  return getLoader();
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError)
                    return  Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                  else
                    return  _getDrawer(snapshot.data);
              }
            }),
```

**Initializing Observable:**

```
 final _assignStudentSetter = PublishSubject<dynamic>();

 Observable<List<AssignMilestoneModel>> get studentsToAssign =>
      _studentsToAssignFetcher.stream;
```

**Method that add's data to Stream:**

```
 postStudentsToAssign(int studyingClass, String milestoneId, String subject,
      List studentList) async {
    var response = await provider.postAssignedStudents(
        studyingClass, milestoneId, subject, studentList);
    _assignStudentSetter.sink.add(response);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send `null` to the stream, so the `snapshot.connectionState` changes to `active`. I don't know why and whether it's official solution, but it works (at least now). I found this accidentally.
I would like the Flutter team to explain how to set snapshot's connectionState. It's not clear from [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) documentation. It seems you should replace the stream with a new one to have `snapshot` in `waiting` state. But it's agains the logic you want to implement.

I checked `StreamBuilder` source to find out that the `AsyncSnapshot.connectionState` starts as `waiting` (after stream is connected), after receiving data changes to `active`. `snapshot.hasData` returns true if `snapshot.data != null`. That's how following code works.

```
class SearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final StreamController<SearchResult> _searchStreamController = StreamController<SearchResult>();
  final SearchService _service = SearchService();

  void _doSearch(String text) async {
    if (text?.isNotEmpty ?? false) {
      _searchStreamController.add(null);
      _searchService.search(text)
          .then((SearchResult result) => _searchStreamController.add(result))
          .catchError((e) => _searchStreamController.addError(e));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        SearchBar(
          onChanged: (text) => _doSearch(text),
        ),
        StreamBuilder<SearchResult>(
          stream: _searchStreamController.stream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<SearchResult> snapshot) {
            Widget widget;
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              widget = Expanded(
                // show search result
              );
            }
            else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              widget = Expanded(
                 // show error
              );
            }
            else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active){
              widget = Expanded(
                // show loading
              );
            }
            else {
              // empty
              widget = Container();
            }
            return widget;
          },
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```